# How to find Fitness API on Developer Console for Google Fit Project?

Tags: android, google-fit

I am doing the steps mentioned in in https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started to implement a simple fitness android app.

But when I want to do this:

Activate the Fitness API Go to the Google Developers Console. In the left sidebar, click APIs and Auth. Find the Fitness API and set its status to ON.

I can not find the Fitness API.

Where can I see this API? I could not find it on the list of APIs on https://console.developers.google.com/project/...

Comment: It will be available after release:
The preview release contains the Google Fit APIs for Android, but it does not contain the REST API or the Android Wear APIs, which will be included in the official release.
https://developers.google.com/fit/preview

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to do this step while in the developer preview. This will be necessary once the Google Fit API comes out of the developer preview.

Till then, enjoy the ease!

Comment: If we don't do this step while in the developer preview, why is this step mentioned right after the step that says "Get the Developer Preview"? https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started

Comment: I asked this myself and then tried to use the API. It just works, for now. My explanation would be, we have API support very minimal and the document was written futuristic.

Answer (score 1):

The API is public and available to everyone now. You should see it in the list of all google APIs for any particular project.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. You can search for fitness API in the searchbox and it gives the result. Then turn it ON